# Several lock waits occurring in innodb status

Tags: mysql, locking, innodb

How do I correct this issue?

Semaphores:

```
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: reservation count 44460135
--Thread 140103924827904 has waited at btr0cur.cc line 545 for 3.00 seconds the semaphore:
S-lock on RW-latch at 0x7f6d80c19968 created in file dict0dict.cc line 2652
a writer (thread id 140108634085120) has reserved it in mode  exclusive
number of readers 0, waiters flag 1, lock_word: 0
Last time read locked in file btr0cur.cc line 545
Last time write locked in file /build/mysql-5.6-Clh7l4/mysql-5.6-5.6.30/storage/innobase/btr/btr0cur.cc line 536
--Thread 140104012134144 has waited at btr0cur.cc line 545 for 3.00 seconds the semaphore:
S-lock on RW-latch at 0x7f6d80c19968 created in file dict0dict.cc line 2652
a writer (thread id 140108634085120) has reserved it in mode  exclusive
number of readers 0, waiters flag 1, lock_word: 0
Last time read locked in file btr0cur.cc line 545
Last time write locked in file /build/mysql-5.6-Clh7l4/mysql-5.6-5.6.30/storage/innobase/btr/btr0cur.cc line 536
--Thread 140103969986304 has waited at buf0buf.cc line 2576 for 3.00 seconds the semaphore:
S-lock on RW-latch at 0x7f768f0bfb40 created in file buf0buf.cc line 1069
a writer (thread id 140108040070912) has reserved it in mode  exclusive
number of readers 0, waiters flag 1, lock_word: 0
Last time read locked in file row0sel.cc line 4138
Last time write locked in file /build/mysql-5.6-Clh7l4/mysql-5.6-5.6.30/storage/innobase/buf/buf0buf.cc line 3691
--Thread 140103901345536 has waited at btr0cur.cc line 545 for 3.00 seconds the semaphore:
S-lock on RW-latch at 0x7f6d80932598 created in file dict0dict.cc line 2652
a writer (thread id 140108638701312) has reserved it in mode  exclusive
number of readers 0, waiters flag 1, lock_word: 0
Last time read locked in file btr0cur.cc line 545
Last time write locked in file /build/mysql-5.6-Clh7l4/mysql-5.6-5.6.30/storage/innobase/btr/btr0cur.cc line 536
--Thread 140108620437248 has waited at btr0cur.cc line 545 for 3.00 seconds the semaphore:
S-lock on RW-latch at 0x7f6d80c19968 created in file dict0dict.cc line 2652
a writer (thread id 140108634085120) has reserved it in mode  exclusive
number of readers 0, waiters flag 1, lock_word: 0
Last time read locked in file btr0cur.cc line 545
Last time write locked in file /build/mysql-5.6-Clh7l4/mysql-5.6-5.6.30/storage/innobase/btr/btr0cur.cc line 536
--Thread 140108058334976 has waited at btr0cur.cc line 545 for 3.00 seconds the semaphore:
S-lock on RW-latch at 0x7f6d80c19968 created in file dict0dict.cc line 2652
a writer (thread id 140108634085120) has reserved it in mode  exclusive
number of readers 0, waiters flag 1, lock_word: 0
Last time read locked in file btr0cur.cc line 545
Last time write locked in file /build/mysql-5.6-Clh7l4/mysql-5.6-5.6.30/storage/innobase/btr/btr0cur.cc line 536
--Thread 140108068169472 has waited at btr0cur.cc line 545 for 3.00 seconds the semaphore:
S-lock on RW-latch at 0x7f6d80932598 created in file dict0dict.cc line 2652
a writer (thread id 140108638701312) has reserved it in mode  exclusive
number of readers 0, waiters flag 1, lock_word: 0
Last time read locked in file btr0cur.cc line 545
Last time write locked in file /build/mysql-5.6-Clh7l4/mysql-5.6-5.6.30/storage/innobase/btr/btr0cur.cc line 536
--Thread 140103927838464 has waited at trx0undo.cc line 1778 for 2.00 seconds the semaphore:
Mutex at 0x55c133826070 created file trx0rseg.cc line 196, lock var 1
waiters flag 1
--Thread 140107814848256 has waited at buf0buf.cc line 2576 for 2.00 seconds the semaphore:
S-lock on RW-latch at 0x7f70c48939c0 created in file buf0buf.cc line 1069
a writer (thread id 140103902750464) has reserved it in mode  exclusive
number of readers 0, waiters flag 1, lock_word: 0
Last time read locked in file btr0cur.cc line 3592
Last time write locked in file /build/mysql-5.6-Clh7l4/mysql-5.6-5.6.30/storage/innobase/buf/buf0buf.cc line 3691
--Thread 140104111482624 has waited at buf0buf.cc line 2576 for 2.00 seconds the semaphore:
S-lock on RW-latch at 0x7f6f56d8d6c0 created in file buf0buf.cc line 1069
a writer (thread id 140103978817280) has reserved it in mode  exclusive
number of readers 0, waiters flag 1, lock_word: 0
Last time read locked in file buf0flu.cc line 1056
Last time write locked in file /build/mysql-5.6-Clh7l4/mysql-5.6-5.6.30/storage/innobase/buf/buf0buf.cc line 3691
--Thread 140108630472448 has waited at trx0undo.cc line 1778 for 2.00 seconds the semaphore:
Mutex at 0x55c133828b70 created file trx0rseg.cc line 196, lock var 1
waiters flag 1
--Thread 140104054683392 has waited at btr0cur.cc line 545 for 2.00 seconds the semaphore:
S-lock on RW-latch at 0x7f6d80c19968 created in file dict0dict.cc line 2652
a writer (thread id 140108634085120) has reserved it in mode  exclusive
number of readers 0, waiters flag 1, lock_word: 0
Last time read locked in file btr0cur.cc line 545
Last time write locked in file /build/mysql-5.6-Clh7l4/mysql-5.6-5.6.30/storage/innobase/btr/btr0cur.cc line 536
--Thread 140104080574208 has waited at btr0cur.cc line 536 for 2.00 seconds the semaphore:
X-lock (wait_ex) on RW-latch at 0x7f6d80c78b78 created in file dict0dict.cc line 2652
a writer (thread id 140104080574208) has reserved it in mode  wait exclusive
number of readers 2, waiters flag 0, lock_word: fffffffffffffffe
Last time read locked in file btr0cur.cc line 545
Last time write locked in file /build/mysql-5.6-Clh7l4/mysql-5.6-5.6.30/storage/innobase/btr/btr0cur.cc line 536
--Thread 140103885088512 has waited at row0ins.cc line 2338 for 2.00 seconds the semaphore:
X-lock on RW-latch at 0x7f6de4392d40 created in file buf0buf.cc line 1069
a writer (thread id 140108644722432) has reserved it in mode  exclusive
number of readers 0, waiters flag 1, lock_word: 0
Last time read locked in file row0sel.cc line 4138
Last time write locked in file /build/mysql-5.6-Clh7l4/mysql-5.6-5.6.30/storage/innobase/row/row0ins.cc line 2338
--Thread 140103919408896 has waited at buf0buf.cc line 2576 for 2.00 seconds the semaphore:
S-lock on RW-latch at 0x7f6f521ee9c0 created in file buf0buf.cc line 1069
a writer (thread id 140104002500352) has reserved it in mode  exclusive
number of readers 0, waiters flag 1, lock_word: 0
Last time read locked in file buf0flu.cc line 1056
Last time write locked in file /build/mysql-5.6-Clh7l4/mysql-5.6-5.6.30/storage/innobase/buf/buf0buf.cc line 3691
--Thread 140108062349056 has waited at btr0cur.cc line 545 for 2.00 seconds the semaphore:
S-lock on RW-latch at 0x7f6d80c19968 created in file dict0dict.cc line 2652
a writer (thread id 140108634085120) has reserved it in mode  exclusive
number of readers 0, waiters flag 1, lock_word: 0
Last time read locked in file btr0cur.cc line 545
Last time write locked in file /build/mysql-5.6-Clh7l4/mysql-5.6-5.6.30/storage/innobase/btr/btr0cur.cc line 536
--Thread 140103889905408 has waited at btr0cur.cc line 545 for 2.00 seconds the semaphore:
S-lock on RW-latch at 0x7f6d80c19968 created in file dict0dict.cc line 2652
a writer (thread id 140108634085120) has reserved it in mode  exclusive
number of readers 0, waiters flag 1, lock_word: 0
Last time read locked in file btr0cur.cc line 545
Last time write locked in file /build/mysql-5.6-Clh7l4/mysql-5.6-5.6.30/storage/innobase/btr/btr0cur.cc line 536
--Thread 140108069373696 has waited at row0ins.cc line 2338 for 2.00 seconds the semaphore:
X-lock on RW-latch at 0x7f7235c3ccc0 created in file buf0buf.cc line 1069
a writer (thread id 140108613412608) has reserved it in mode  exclusive
number of readers 0, waiters flag 1, lock_word: 0
Last time read locked in file row0purge.cc line 100
Last time write locked in file /build/mysql-5.6-Clh7l4/mysql-5.6-5.6.30/storage/innobase/row/row0ins.cc line 2338
--Thread 140108093859584 has waited at btr0cur.cc line 545 for 2.00 seconds the semaphore:
S-lock on RW-latch at 0x7f6d80932598 created in file dict0dict.cc line 2652
a writer (thread id 140108638701312) has reserved it in mode  exclusive
number of readers 0, waiters flag 1, lock_word: 0
Last time read locked in file btr0cur.cc line 545
Last time write locked in file /build/mysql-5.6-Clh7l4/mysql-5.6-5.6.30/storage/innobase/btr/btr0cur.cc line 536
--Thread 140103988651776 has waited at trx0undo.cc line 1778 for 2.00 seconds the semaphore:
Mutex at 0x55c133818b20 created file trx0rseg.cc line 196, lock var 1
waiters flag 1
--Thread 140108086433536 has waited at row0ins.cc line 2338 for 2.00 seconds the semaphore:
X-lock on RW-latch at 0x7f7235c3ccc0 created in file buf0buf.cc line 1069
a writer (thread id 140108613412608) has reserved it in mode  exclusive
number of readers 0, waiters flag 1, lock_word: 0
Last time read locked in file row0purge.cc line 100
Last time write locked in file /build/mysql-5.6-Clh7l4/mysql-5.6-5.6.30/storage/innobase/row/row0ins.cc line 2338
--Thread 140104067929856 has waited at row0ins.cc line 2338 for 2.00 seconds the semaphore:
X-lock on RW-latch at 0x7f70c87b7e40 created in file buf0buf.cc line 1069
a writer (thread id 140103918204672) has reserved it in mode  exclusive
number of readers 0, waiters flag 1, lock_word: 0
Last time read locked in file row0purge.cc line 100
Last time write locked in file /build/mysql-5.6-Clh7l4/mysql-5.6-5.6.30/storage/innobase/row/row0ins.cc line 2338
--Thread 140104054281984 has waited at buf0buf.cc line 2576 for 2.00 seconds the semaphore:
S-lock on RW-latch at 0x7f77fa5ab4c0 created in file buf0buf.cc line 1069
a writer (thread id 140108061947648) has reserved it in mode  exclusive
number of readers 0, waiters flag 1, lock_word: 0
Last time read locked in file btr0cur.cc line 3592
Last time write locked in file /build/mysql-5.6-Clh7l4/mysql-5.6-5.6.30/storage/innobase/buf/buf0buf.cc line 3691
--Thread 140108080211712 has waited at btr0cur.cc line 545 for 2.00 seconds the semaphore:
S-lock on RW-latch at 0x7f6d80932598 created in file dict0dict.cc line 2652
a writer (thread id 140108638701312) has reserved it in mode  exclusive
number of readers 0, waiters flag 1, lock_word: 0
Last time read locked in file btr0cur.cc line 545
Last time write locked in file /build/mysql-5.6-Clh7l4/mysql-5.6-5.6.30/storage/innobase/btr/btr0cur.cc line 536
--Thread 140103977813760 has waited at row0ins.cc line 2338 for 2.00 seconds the semaphore:
X-lock on RW-latch at 0x7f6de4392d40 created in file buf0buf.cc line 1069
a writer (thread id 140108644722432) has reserved it in mode  exclusive
number of readers 0, waiters flag 1, lock_word: 0
Last time read locked in file row0sel.cc line 4138
Last time write locked in file /build/mysql-5.6-Clh7l4/mysql-5.6-5.6.30/storage/innobase/row/row0ins.cc line 2338
--Thread 140104031201024 has waited at buf0buf.cc line 2576 for 2.00 seconds the semaphore:
S-lock on RW-latch at 0x7f76885f6f40 created in file buf0buf.cc line 1069
a writer (thread id 140103887697664) has reserved it in mode  exclusive
number of readers 0, waiters flag 1, lock_word: 0
Last time read locked in file buf0flu.cc line 1056
Last time write locked in file /build/mysql-5.6-Clh7l4/mysql-5.6-5.6.30/storage/innobase/buf/buf0buf.cc line 3691
--Thread 140103888099072 has waited at row0sel.cc line 4138 for 2.00 seconds the semaphore:
S-lock on RW-latch at 0x7f7235c3ccc0 created in file buf0buf.cc line 1069
a writer (thread id 140108613412608) has reserved it in mode  exclusive
number of readers 0, waiters flag 1, lock_word: 0
Last time read locked in file row0purge.cc line 100
Last time write locked in file /build/mysql-5.6-Clh7l4/mysql-5.6-5.6.30/storage/innobase/row/row0ins.cc line 2338
--Thread 140108636292864 has waited at trx0undo.cc line 1778 for 2.00 seconds the semaphore:
Mutex at 0x55c133825050 created file trx0rseg.cc line 196, lock var 1
waiters flag 1
--Thread 140104021165824 has waited at trx0undo.cc line 1778 for 2.00 seconds the semaphore:
Mutex at 0x55c133825b10 created file trx0rseg.cc line 196, lock var 1
waiters flag 1
--Thread 140103936669440 has waited at trx0undo.cc line 1778 for 2.00 seconds the semaphore:
Mutex at 0x55c133826070 created file trx0rseg.cc line 196, lock var 1
waiters flag 1
--Thread 140103983634176 has waited at trx0undo.cc line 1778 for 2.00 seconds the semaphore:
Mutex at 0x55c133827090 created file trx0rseg.cc line 196, lock var 1
waiters flag 1
--Thread 140103897130752 has waited at trx0undo.cc line 1778 for 2.00 seconds the semaphore:
Mutex at 0x55c133828b70 created file trx0rseg.cc line 196, lock var 1
waiters flag 1
--Thread 140104084788992 has waited at trx0undo.cc line 1778 for 2.00 seconds the semaphore:
Mutex at 0x55c133829b90 created file trx0rseg.cc line 196, lock var 1
waiters flag 1
--Thread 140108119348992 has waited at trx0undo.cc line 1778 for 2.00 seconds the semaphore:
Mutex at 0x55c13382b670 created file trx0rseg.cc line 196, lock var 1
waiters flag 1
--Thread 140104088803072 has waited at row0ins.cc line 2338 for 2.00 seconds the semaphore:
X-lock on RW-latch at 0x7f73a9cbb0c0 created in file buf0buf.cc line 1069
a writer (thread id 140103906563840) has reserved it in mode  exclusive
number of readers 0, waiters flag 1, lock_word: 0
Last time read locked in file row0sel.cc line 4138
Last time write locked in file /build/mysql-5.6-Clh7l4/mysql-5.6-5.6.30/storage/innobase/row/row0ins.cc line 2338
--Thread 140104042440448 has waited at trx0undo.cc line 1778 for 2.00 seconds the semaphore:
Mutex at 0x55c133806940 created file trx0rseg.cc line 196, lock var 1
waiters flag 1
--Thread 140104107669248 has waited at trx0undo.cc line 1778 for 2.00 seconds the semaphore:
Mutex at 0x55c133807d10 created file trx0rseg.cc line 196, lock var 1
waiters flag 1
--Thread 140107815851776 has waited at row0ins.cc line 2338 for 2.00 seconds the semaphore:
X-lock on RW-latch at 0x7f7517990ec0 created in file buf0buf.cc line 1069
a writer (thread id 140107830904576) has reserved it in mode  exclusive
number of readers 0, waiters flag 1, lock_word: 0
Last time read locked in file row0sel.cc line 3500
Last time write locked in file /build/mysql-5.6-Clh7l4/mysql-5.6-5.6.30/storage/innobase/row/row0ins.cc line 2338
--Thread 140104001296128 has waited at trx0undo.cc line 1778 for 2.00 seconds the semaphore:
Mutex at 0x55c13380a810 created file trx0rseg.cc line 196, lock var 1
waiters flag 1
--Thread 140104003102464 has waited at trx0undo.cc line 1778 for 2.00 seconds the semaphore:
Mutex at 0x55c13380c8a0 created file trx0rseg.cc line 196, lock var 1
waiters flag 1
--Thread 140104004708096 has waited at row0ins.cc line 2338 for 2.00 seconds the semaphore:
X-lock on RW-latch at 0x7f6de1508240 created in file buf0buf.cc line 1069
a writer (thread id 140104082781952) has reserved it in mode  exclusive
number of readers 0, waiters flag 1, lock_word: 0
Last time read locked in file row0sel.cc line 4138
Last time write locked in file /build/mysql-5.6-Clh7l4/mysql-5.6-5.6.30/storage/innobase/row/row0ins.cc line 2338
--Thread 140107825886976 has waited at trx0undo.cc line 1778 for 2.00 seconds the semaphore:
Mutex at 0x55c13380de20 created file trx0rseg.cc line 196, lock var 1
waiters flag 1
--Thread 140103983232768 has waited at trx0undo.cc line 1778 for 2.00 seconds the semaphore:
Mutex at 0x55c13380ee40 created file trx0rseg.cc line 196, lock var 1
waiters flag 1
--Thread 140104025380608 has waited at row0sel.cc line 4138 for 2.00 seconds the semaphore:
S-lock on RW-latch at 0x7f70c81360c0 created in file buf0buf.cc line 1069
a writer (thread id 140104042440448) has reserved it in mode  exclusive
number of readers 0, waiters flag 1, lock_word: 0
Last time read locked in file row0sel.cc line 4138
Last time write locked in file /build/mysql-5.6-Clh7l4/mysql-5.6-5.6.30/storage/innobase/row/row0upd.cc line 2354
--Thread 140108077401856 has waited at btr0cur.cc line 545 for 2.00 seconds the semaphore:
S-lock on RW-latch at 0x7f6d80932598 created in file dict0dict.cc line 2652
a writer (thread id 140108638701312) has reserved it in mode  exclusive
number of readers 0, waiters flag 1, lock_word: 0
Last time read locked in file btr0cur.cc line 545
Last time write locked in file /build/mysql-5.6-Clh7l4/mysql-5.6-5.6.30/storage/innobase/btr/btr0cur.cc line 536
```

Comment: What SQL statements were running at this time?

Comment: Cleanup the title and add the question to the body.